# Why does Clojure represent xml documents as hash-maps?

Tags: xml, xslt, clojure, lisp

Can xml be a native clojure datatype and allow simple definitions like

```
(def myxml <inventors><clojure>Rich Hickey</clojure></inventors>)
```

What prevents the current parsers from doing this

```
{:inventors {:clojure "Rich Hickey"}}
```

instead of this

```
{:tag :inventors, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :clojure, :attrs nil, :content ["Rich Hickey"]}]}
```

A cursory search for similar representations in other lisps i see [SXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SXML)
which supports namespaces.

Comment: In `{:inventors {:clojure "Rich Hickey"}}`, where would you put attrs values if there were any?

Comment: No idea @user1184248 also namespaces and duplicate node names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example doesn't work already when you enter another inventor:

```
{:inventors
  {:clojure "Rich Hickey"}
  {:lisp "John McCarthy"}}
```

(Error: that is not a map.)

If you put both into one submap, you cannot have more than one child of a given type.  That is important because the example XML structure is not properly designed.  It should be something like:

```
<inventors>
  <inventor>
    <language>Clojure</language>
    <person>Rich Hickey</person>
  </inventor>
  <inventor>
    <language>Lisp</language>
    <person>John McCarthy</person>
  </inventor>
</inventors>
```

What you could do is use lists or vectors directly, instead of explicitly naming the components of a single tag:

```
[:inventors {}
  [:inventor {}
    [:language {} "Clojure"]
    [:person {} "Rich Hickey"]]
  [:inventor {}
    [:language {} "Lisp"]
    [:person {} "John McCarthy"]]]
```

That would look like this in the commonly used map structure:

```
{:tag :inventors
 :attrs nil
 :content [{:tag :inventor
            :attrs nil
            :content [{:tag :language
                       :attrs nil
                       :content "Clojure"}
                      {:tag :person
                       :attrs nil
                       :content "Rich Hickey"}]}
           {:tag :inventor
            :attrs nil
            :content [{:tag :language
                       :attrs nil
                       :content "Lisp"}
                      {:tag :person
                       :attrs nil
                       :content "John McCarthy"}]}]}
```

This might look like the vector proposal above is cleaner, but you would have to define accessor functions to (sensibly) work with those vectors.  The maps already are their own accessor functions in Clojure, so you can directly and idiomatically work with them.

Comment: You are right about the xml not being designed properly but unfortunately that is valid xml and applications I would like to work with produce or consume xmls like that.

Comment: @KobbyPemson: I pity you, but that is irrelevant for the question at hand because you do not want to design an XML representation that can only represent a tiny subset of XML documents, do you?  :)

Comment: good point but you have to admit the current representation is less readable than xml and any representation should allow for lossless round tripping on any valid xml.

Comment: Claiming that it is (even) less readable than XML is pretty harsh, but it really is not very readable.  For that, the vector representation is much better.  However, the idiomatic accessors are a valid argument too, since they enable the code manipulating the representation to be more readable (for a Clojure programmer).

Comment: It's not a problem of literal representation (with focus on readability and writability) but of in-memory representation (with focus on consistent and simple manipulation of a good subset of the XML infoset). For your own application you could and maybe even should find a model more suited to your problem rather than piggy-backing on the model of the data format. It's all data, feel free to convet back and forth, Clojure is very well equipped for that. It's not because you get and write XML that you should tint your data processing wth XMLness. Clojure allows for lightweight modeling.

Comment: @Svante the hiccup/vector notation works much better but I can't find any libraries that make accessing and transforming it as intuitive as doing (get-in ....) and (for [x y z ] ...). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Substitute square braces for the curly ones and what you are talking about is [hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) format.

```
user=> (hiccup.core/html [:inventors [:clojure "Rich Hickey"]])
"<inventors><clojure>Rich Hickey</clojure></inventors>"
```

You can use hiccup-like style with [data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml).

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? (xml -> hash-map).